# What does the response Error in 1:indiceNA[lalo[i]] : NA/NaN argument in R mean?

Tags: r

I have a regularized trajectory (Breg) in R (has a lot of NA values -> came from irregular.

Breg:

head(Breg)

```
*********** List of class ltraj ***********

Type of the traject: Type II (time recorded)
* Time zone: UTC *
Regular traject. Time lag between two locs: 900 seconds

Characteristics of the bursts:
    id burst nb.reloc  NAs          date.begin            date.end
1 2172  2172     4449 1683 2015-08-07 00:22:00 2015-09-22 08:22:00


 infolocs provided. The following variables are available:
[1] "pkey"

> head(Breg[[1]])
         x       y                date dx dy dist  dt        R2n abs.angle       rel.angle
1 409662.0 6448915 2015-08-07 00:22:00 NA NA   NA 900   0.000000        NA        NA
2       NA      NA 2015-08-07 00:37:00 NA NA   NA 900         NA        NA        NA
3 409663.9 6448913 2015-08-07 00:52:00 NA NA   NA 900   9.245614        NA        NA
4       NA      NA 2015-08-07 01:07:00 NA NA   NA 900         NA        NA        NA
5 409633.7 6448906 2015-08-07 01:22:00 NA NA   NA 900 885.556316        NA        NA
6       NA      NA 2015-08-07 01:37:00 NA NA   NA 900         NA        NA        NA

List of 1
 $ :'data.frame':   4449 obs. of  10 variables:
  ..$ x        : num [1:4449] 409662 NA 409664 NA 409634 ...
  ..$ y        : num [1:4449] 6448915 NA 6448913 NA 6448906 ...
  ..$ date     : POSIXct[1:4449], format: "2015-08-07 00:22:00" "2015-08-07  00:37:00" "2015-08-07 00:52:00" "2015-08-07 01:07:00" ...
  ..$ dx       : num [1:4449] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ dy       : num [1:4449] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ dist     : num [1:4449] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ dt       : num [1:4449] 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 900 ...
  ..$ R2n      : num [1:4449] 0 NA 9.25 NA 885.56 ...
  ..$ abs.angle: num [1:4449] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ rel.angle: num [1:4449] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "id")= chr "2172"
  ..- attr(*, "burst")= chr "2172"
  ..- attr(*, "infolocs")='data.frame': 4449 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ pkey: int [1:4449] 1 NA 2 NA 3 NA 4 NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "ltraj" "list"
 - attr(*, "typeII")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "regular")= logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "proj4string")=Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. ..@ projargs: chr NAI'm following the Gueguen method for segmenting my  trajectory, explained in the adehabitatlt pdf: Analysis of Animal Movements in  R.
```

I have created the models based on my tested means, got the probability densities for each model and estimated the number of segments:

```
(limod <- as.list(paste("dnorm(dist, mean =", tested.means,",sd = 5000)")))

mod <- modpartltraj(Breg, limod)
mod
bestpartmod(mod)
Maximum likelihood for K =  4
```

But when i try to partition the trajectory into the 4 segments i get this error:

```
> pm <- partmod.ltraj(Breg, 4, mod)
Error in 1:indiceNA[lalo[i]] : NA/NaN argument
```

I'm not quite sure what it means, it looks like R is having problems finding the exact place to cut off between segments because of my NA values?
Not sure how to get around it.

Kind regards,

Sam

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: @akrun: i supplied the information on the object Breg, does that help? Not sure how to supply you with a small sample of this dataset...